# gwt native DnD - prevent inner components from becoming the drag proxy

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I am using native GWT DnD. The functional parts work ok. However, I have trouble controlling the drag proxy.

The drag object is a HTMLPanel which contains  and  elements. I can make the entire HTMLPanel the drag proxy if I carefully start the drag from a corner. However, if I start from inside the img or span, the image or the text inside the span become the drag proxy.

I fooled around a bit with imgElement.setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_FALSE); but it didn't do any good.

Any one knows how to prevent the image/span element from being picked up as the drag proxy?

Comment: I found it. event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(getElement(), 0, 0);

Comment: next question, is there a way to manipulate the drag proxy such as change its background color using css?